# Как привязать приложение к аккаунту Google?

Tags: java, android

Нужно привязать приложение к аккаунту Google, чтобы при смене девайса или на разных девайсах с одним аккаунтом все работало. 
Как это делается? 
Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону Firebase, которая как раз и создавалась в том числе и для подобных задач - кросс-платформенная авторизация без собственного бекэнда.

Начать можно тут: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/
Здесь описаны шаги по добавлению авторизации в своё Android-приложение.

Так же есть готовые примеры: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

Answer (score 1):

Можно по разному сделать.

1. Можно на своем бэкенде хранить что-то что доступно только конкретному пользователю, с какого бы устройства не заходил в ваше приложение.
2. Можно хранить эту информацию на серверах Гугла, и он сам будет заботиться о синхронизации между устройствами.

Как вариант 2 вам может подойти:
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder

Comment: А можно узнать адрес электронной почты, к которому привязан аккаунт, т.е. считать его из устройства и привязаться к нему?

Comment: Можно с помощью `AccountManager`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccounts()  
Не забывайте что для этого нужно разрешение https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS